# Read emails from multiple account, is that possible?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I created a new gmail project using my own google account. after creating the credential, I could use the following code to fetch my own emails.

```
result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
```

My question is what should I do if I need to fetch emails from other accounts, such as 20 different accounts? list all of their userIds in the list function?

Thanks

Comment: You created a new Gmail project? Do you mean GCP? Are you a Google Workspace Admin?

Comment: If you're an Admin for a Google Domain, then its possible by Delegating Domain-Wide Authority to a service account within said the domain.

Answer (score 0):

When you ran your code the first time it asked you to authncate yourself, login to google and consent to the application accessing your email.

You will need to do this for each of the twenty users.  Each user must grant your application access to their data only then can you access it.  then for each user you can do

```
result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, so you mean I need to run the script 20 times, each time a new unauthorized email address, and then login to google and sonsent?